# Angular app in subfolder Laravel + htaccess

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I have a laravel 5 installation. Works perfect.
`.htaccess` inside the public folder is default and works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Inside the `public` (root) folder i have a folder named `webapp`

`webapp` includes a web version of my app build with `angularjs` and it needs `push states`

the ideal `.htaccess` inside the `webapp` folder would be:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    # html5 pushstate (history) support:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]

</ifModule>
```

But it seems the `.htaccess` inside the `webapp` folder is not triggered.

I probably need to write the conditions and rules inside the `laravel` `public` folder. But i'm not sure how to handle this and in what order etc.

Can someone help me to combine the 2 `.htaccess` files into one to place inside the `public` folder.

Comment: The particular situation happens only on my localhost with MAMP.
On my server both .htaccess files are parsed.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
bash-3.2$ cat .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] #This creates a redirect loop for angular

    # IF the resource does not exist as an actual directory...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # OR an actual file...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # AND is being requested from angular directory a/
    # THEN send it to the angular routing file
    RewriteRule ^(a/.*) /a/index.html [NC,L]

    # IF the resource does not exist as an actual directory...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # OR an actual file...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # THEN send the traffic to laravel routing
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: This answer also works if you have a setup like mine: Angular in `public/`, but also an API managed by Laravel under `yoursite.com/api/`: just replace `^(a/.*) /a/index.html` with `^(api/.*) /index.php` and `RewriteRule ^ index.php` with `RewriteRule ^ index.html`. Make sure you have both `index` files int eh same directory: .php is the Laravel one, `.html` is the Angular one.